# jupyter notebook: with open('path', 'wb') as file, then write results in unicode decode error

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook, byte

** **EDIT:** **
I retried the script on a Windows Machine with Python 3.8.1 and it just ran.
So to me, this seems to be a specific jupyter notebook error...

---

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I swear I could not find my problem on here.

What am I trying?
I have a small python 3 script which uses mysql.connector to pull an image blob from the database.
I then want to write the file to the disk, via pythons context manager:

```py
[...]
with open('/path/to/file.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(cursor.fetchone()[0])
[...]
```

this throws an error regarding utf-8 decode:

```py
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

this leaves me puzzled - shouldnt python just write the output of mysql directly to the file, as-is?
I thought the file mode 'wb' does this.

The script is running in jupyter notebook.
even more concerning is the fact that the script works just fine when run under python 2.7 on mac OS X.

does anybody have a hint why this happens?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post the complete error?

Comment: there is nothing more. just the usual stack of related fails that are not the cause of the exception.

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte`

I just tried running the script on a windows machine with py3.8.1 and it just works.
so this seems to be a specific jupyter notebook error...